# C# unzip .EXE file in memory

Tags: c#, memory, zip, unzip

After some research (around 1 day) I realize that I need some help plz.

**My problem to solve:**

I'm trying to unzip an `.exe` file, but I can't write the result to disk (it's a constraint).

I need to keep in memory this one, for example in a `Stream` class or even string class.

Just to complete my question:

- I don't know which tool was used to generate it.
- .Net Framework 4.5

**What I tried:**

- I used `Process` class but there is a validation step and I want do that in background
- I try to explore GZip / ZipFile Class but that was a failure

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you just trying to unzip it, or are you trying to execute it as well?

Comment: i just trying to unzip it in memory, in need the content who is inside (the txt file)

Comment: Have you looked into a third party library, like SharpZipLib?

Comment: I haven't explore SharpZipLib but if you know how do that with this library that can be the solution...

Comment: There is a sample here: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/samples/cs/unzipfile/UnZipFile.cs note that the `FileStream` at the end could easily be replaced by a `MemoryStream` which is held entirely in memory.

Comment: it's not good because he can't decompress the file, it's a .EXE. Your method works with a file with .zip extension but it's not my case...

Comment: I apologize, I thought you were trying to unzip a file that contained an exe.

Answer (score 2):

If you can build on .NET Framework 4.5 or later, use the classes from `System.IO.Compression` (remember to add a reference to `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` at your project level):

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;

public static string GetTextfileFromZip(string zipFilepath, string txtFilename)
{
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipFilepath, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = GetZipArchiveEntry(zipArchive, txtFilename);
        using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static ZipArchiveEntry GetZipArchiveEntry(ZipArchive zipArchive, string zipEntryName)
{
    return zipArchive.Entries.First<ZipArchiveEntry>(n => n.FullName.Equals(zipEntryName));
}
```

Note: if your archive is a self-extracting archive with a .EXE extension this will still work. Just pass in the full path to the exe to the function.
The second parameter is the name/path to the text file within the archive. So if the text file is in the archive root, it will just be e.g. "file.txt", otherwise if it is in a folder called `sub` then the parameter should be `@"sub\file.txt"`

Comment: Thx for your help but when i use this method i obtain : End-of-central-directory signature not found exception.

Comment: In that case, your .exe is most likely not a self-extracting zip archive, or somehow corrupted and I can't help you any further. To confirm, see if you can open the .exe file with WinRAR or another archiving application.

Comment: i can open it with my 7zip, it works fine when i do an extract manually

Comment: In that case it seems your archive is a RAR and not a ZIP archive and you can't use the .NET System.IO.Compression library to read it. I'll leave my answer here in case it's useful to someone else who needs to decompress a self-extracting ZIP .exe file. You should instead try something like the "free" [Chilkat library](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/rar_unrar.asp). I say "free" because while the Chilkat library requires paid licensing, it states that the RAR functionality is freeware. I'm not sure if you'll be able to use it for free if you only use it for RAR extraction.

Answer (score -1):

This is more simple way

```
using System;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace zipReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("C:\\Temp\\D20190827.exe", "C:\\Temp\\");
            Console.WriteLine("Extract Done!");
        }       
    }
}
```